# std::map<std::variant, std::variant> with mapping from KeyType to ValueType

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, type-safety

I'm trying to create a `std::map` of variant to variant with a mapping from the `KeyType` to the `MappedType`.

This works for up to around 100 key types or so: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3959534e4fa38caa. When I attempt to compile with 200 key types, GCC thinks hard for a while and then gives up with the error:

```
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
```

I believe it may be a problem with the parameter pack being too large. Is there a more scalable solution?

I include below the salient parts of the solution:

```
template<typename Key, typename T>
struct TypeMap {
    using KeyType = Key;
    using MappedType = T;
};

template<typename>
constexpr bool false_v = false;

// End case
template<typename Key, typename...>
struct MappedTypeForKey {
    static_assert(false_v<Key>, "Container mapping for key type not found");
};

// Recursive case
template<typename Key, typename MapKey, typename T, typename... TypeMaps>
struct MappedTypeForKey<Key, TypeMap<MapKey, T>, TypeMaps...> : MappedTypeForKey<Key, TypeMaps...> {
};

// Match case
template<typename Key, typename T, typename... TypeMaps>
struct MappedTypeForKey<Key, TypeMap<Key, T>, TypeMaps...> {
    using Type = T;
};

template<typename... TypeMaps>
struct VariantTypeMapImpl {
    using KeyType = std::variant<typename TypeMaps::KeyType...>;
    using MappedType = std::variant<typename TypeMaps::MappedType...>;
    template<typename Key>
    using TypeForKey = typename MappedTypeForKey<Key, TypeMaps...>::Type;
};

// This is the key part of the code, allowing a developer to extend the map variants
// at the same time as defining the type mappings:
using VariantTypeMap = VariantTypeMapImpl<
    TypeMap<FrogKey, Frog>,
    TypeMap<CatKey, Cat>
>;

class VariantMap {
  public:
    size_t size() const { return map_.size(); }

    template<typename Key>
    void insert(Key key, VariantTypeMap::TypeForKey<Key> value)
    {
        map_.emplace(std::move(key), std::move(value));
    }

    template<typename Key>
    const VariantTypeMap::TypeForKey<Key>& get(const Key& key) const
    {
        return std::get<VariantTypeMap::TypeForKey<Key>>(map_.at(key));
    }

  private:
    std::map<VariantTypeMap::KeyType, VariantTypeMap::MappedType> map_;
};
```

Comment: If I'm understanding the problem right, the problems is in the number of parameters to a template instantiation.  The C++ language spec (in Appendix B) lists recommended minimums for implementation defined quantities.  It lists 1024 as the minimum recommended number of template parameters in a template declaration, and 1024 recursively nested template declarations.  These are recommendations, not requirements, and compilers can limit themselves to fewer...

Comment: ... However, any input to a compiler that causes the compiler to crash reveals a bug in the compiler that should be reported (since there should be a compilation error if a limit is reached, not a crash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requiring quadratically many instantiations of `MappedTypeForKey` if `insert` or `get` are actually instantiated for all `Key` types and they are all distinct, because each lookup will take on average linear time in the number of mapped pairs. Eventually GCC will run out of memory to store these instantiations and crash.

Instead you can get a mapping between types by making use of template argument deduction rules for references to base classes. This does only require linear amount of compile time memory in total and if the compiler has implemented the base class lookup decently, this will take at most logarithmic time per lookup, so that the whole program will hopefully have sub-quadratic compile-time time and memory complexity in the number of mapped pairs:

```
template<typename... TypeMaps>
struct VariantTypeMapImpl {
    using KeyType = std::variant<typename TypeMaps::KeyType...>;
    using MappedType = std::variant<typename TypeMaps::MappedType...>;

    struct map : TypeMaps... {
        template<typename Key, typename Mapped>
        static auto lookup(const TypeMap<Key, Mapped>&) -> Mapped;
    };

    template<typename Key>
    using TypeForKey = decltype(map::template lookup<Key>(map{}));
};
```

This requires all keys to be distinct. Otherwise you will get errors complaining about ambiguous calls or repeated base classes.

Comment: When I try to change to this on Coliru, I get the error: `main.cpp:83:48: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
   83 |     using TypeForKey = decltype(map::lookup<Key>(map{}));`

Comment: @Rai This is already fixed in my answer. It should be `map::template lookup`, not `map::lookup`.

Comment: Thanks, this does work, for some reason I didn't see the update. It also appears to compile a bit faster. Unfortunately with 200 keys, GCC fails with the same error. I'm using 7.3.1 if that is important.

Comment: @Rai Could you post the example that crashes? Maybe I overlooked another issue.

Comment: I'm surprised Coliru will take it, though it times out rather than crashing. Here you go: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd68ce45eb8f921e

Comment: @Rai As far as I can tell that code has linear time and memory usage with the number of pairs. With 200 pairs it takes about 2 minutes on my notebook and uses about 2GB of memory with `-O3`. If your system is not running out of memory, I don't see why it should crash. The time and memory requirement is simply due to the amount of work instantiation of `std::variant` has to do. Remember that it needs to generate constructors/destructors/accessors etc. for all types.

Comment: Also note that this code doesn't actually run into the problem I mentioned in my answer at all. The problem in my answer will manifest when you try to actually insert/get all (or most) of the types, which the linked code doesn't do.

Comment: I'm on `-O2` with debug information. Perhaps it's the GCC version leading to a crash. Nevermind, unless it's possible to get compile time down to the 10s of seconds for up to 500 keys, this will be a non-starter. I have a less attractive alternative that defines the type mapping and `std::variant`s separately.

Comment: @Rai The problem is not the mapping, my answer should take care of that. The problem now is simply the implementation of `std::variant` with that large of a type list. It simply requires generation of a lot of code. It won't matter whether you define it separately or not. It seems unlikely that your design is a good idea in general. You might want to ask specifically about your use case, because I don't see how you could ever need hundreds of different types like that.

Comment: @Rai With debug information it still compiles for me, just takes about double the time and memory.

Comment: Indeed, `std::variant` alone with 200 types fails to compile. I expect this will lead to an alternative using `std::any`, tvm for all the help.